# Export active page to PDF (AppleScript + InDesign)

Tags: applescript, adobe-indesign

I have an AppleScript that exports the active document in InDesign to a PDF on my desktop.

```
--this script exports all opened InDesign document as PDFs

set my_destination to (path to desktop) as string

tell application id "com.adobe.InDesign"
activate
--next line collects all current PDF export presets
set my_pdf_export to get the name of every PDF export preset
--next line makes you choose which preset to use for ALL opened InDesign documents
set my_pdf_choice to (choose from list my_pdf_export) as string
--loop starts here
repeat with this_doc in (active document)
    --next line gets the name of the active InDesign document
    set doc_name to get name of this_doc
    --next 3 lines perform the actual PDF export
    tell this_doc
        export format PDF type to my_destination & (characters 1 thru -6 of doc_name) & ".pdf" using my_pdf_choice without showing options
    end tell
end repeat
end tell
```

The script prompts for a PDF preset selection before exporting.

I'd like the script to export only the active page of the active document.

I've tried a couple things like replacing "active document" with active page", however I am not too knowledgable about AppleScript.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it need to be a PDF? Could you use an exported JPEG instead? (Curious as I can only see a page range reference for exporting images in the InDesign dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you got your code from [This Macscripter question](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=38987), and the code is already in that script. You just need to set the `page range` of InDesign's `PDF Export Preferences`

```
tell PDF export preferences
    set page range to "1, 3-5"
end tell
```

Just make sure to set it back at the end, because this is a persistent application setting.

```
tell PDF export preferences
    set page range to all pages
end tell
```

Comment: I did discover this and I've made an [Alfred workflow](http://www.alfredforum.com/topic/3877-adobe-indesign-pdf-export/) for it